# PHP Script is creating a folder but cannot create a folder inside

Tags: php, permissions, directory, php-safe-mode

I have searched stack overflow and Google for many hours now and cannot find an answer. I have found things that are related but nothing is working.

Here is the code:

```
$oldmask = umask(0);

if(!is_dir("play")){
    mkdir("play", 0777, true);
    chmod("play", 0777);
}
if(!is_dir("play/playTest")){
    mkdir("play/playTest", 0777, true);
    chmod("play/playTest", 0777);
}

umask($oldmask);
```

The directory "play" is created fine, however I get this error when it tries to create the "play/playTest" directory.

`SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid/gid is 178245/178245 is not allowed to access /a/b/c/play owned by uid/gid 25000/25000 in /a/b/c/script.php`

I understand this is a file owner restriction due to safe mode, but why would the user be different when the folder was created in the same script?

I have tried with and without umask and with and without chmod, and many other things but nothing has worked.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since you're using safe mode, you're still using PHP <= 5.3. Deactivate the safe mode, so simple is the solution.

Comment: What's your OS (Operating System)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to turn off safe mode, but why do I need to? I guess I'm wondering why is php creating folders with one owner but reads them as another?

The OS I'm using is OSX-Mavericks, but it's kinda irrelevant given I'm uploading the files to a site via ftp.

Answer (score 0):

This hacky workaround relies on a safe-mode vulnerability:

(you can recursively create directories if you do it using FTP)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#104301

Comment: That most likely works (I haven't tried it), but I'm really more interested in trying to figure out why it's doing what it's doing, rather than finding a hack to work around it. Thank you for the solution though, I may have to use it.

Comment: It boils down to a peculiarity of safe mode. This note tells more, but admittedly it doesn't tell *why* http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php#45917. I fully agree, though. If you can help it, you should not implement a hack. You should turn off safe mode

Comment: I finally got my site admin to disable safe mode, so all is good now. Too bad no one could find a solution to this quirk... :/